# RxSwift - onNext not called when validating UITextField after button was tapped

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Got quite a big problem - have a form with a couple of input fields and would like to validate those using RxSwift.
Everything works fine when I edit the text, but it simply doesn't work when I want to validate those fields after the button has been tapped or even simply bind those fields to button.rx.isEnabled, any help would be appreciated. Code below (mixed with some comments):

```
ViewController:
func setupBindings() {
        self.emailInputField.inputTf
            .rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: self.presenter.emailInputFieldPublishSubject)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        self.messageInputField.inputTv
            .rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: self.presenter.messageInputFieldPublishSubject)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        self.presenter.validateEmail()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] errorMessage in
                self?.emailInputField.error = errorMessage
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        self.presenter.validateMessage()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] errorMessage in
                self?.messageInputField.error = errorMessage
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

// Everything above works fine, error message is set properly as soon as the user taps the input field - that's correct

// rx.tap action is called, flatMap is called, but then subscribe(onNext) is not called, looks like onNext is not emitted or so

        self.submitButton.rx.tap.flatMap { [weak self] (_) -> Observable<String?> in
            guard let context = self else { return Observable.just(nil) }
            return context.presenter.validateEmail()
        }
        .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            SwiftyBeaver.debug("onNext \(value ?? "")")
        }, onError: { (error) in
            SwiftyBeaver.debug("onError \(error)")
        }, onCompleted: {
            SwiftyBeaver.debug("onCompleted")
        }, onDisposed: {
            SwiftyBeaver.debug("onDisposed")
        })
        .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}
```

```
ViewModel:
    let emailInputFieldPublishSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
    let messageInputFieldPublishSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
    func validateEmail() -> Observable<String?> {
        return emailInputFieldPublishSubject.debug().map { $0.validateEmail() }
    }
    func validateMessage() -> Observable<String?> {
        return messageInputFieldPublishSubject.map { $0.validate(minLength: 3, maxLength: 1024) }
    }


// Also have "validateForm" method to validate the whole form after tapping "submitButton", but it doesn't work from the same reason. Don't worry about consent validation, it works just the same.

    func validateForm() -> Observable<Bool> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(self.validateConsent(),
                                        self.validateEmail(),
                                        self.validateMessage())
            .map { (consentError, emailError, messageError) in
                return consentError.isBlank && emailError.isBlank && messageError.isBlank
            }
    }
```

Losing my mind, any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to fix that by myself:

First of all, I had to bind not ControlProperty of a textfield, but instead I had to make it an Observable (`asObservable()`) and then it worked. But that wasn't all - there was an issue because calling rx.text produces another subscription and it may lead to app lags etc.

To fix that I simply passed to the `validateForm()` method observables (as parameters) like that: `Observable.just(emailInputField.inputTf.text)` and then it worked fine :)